Lines of curvature of a surface
I have a question related to the lines of curvature of a surface:
Let $S\subset \mathbb{R^3}$ be a regular surface, and suppose $p\in S$ is not an umbilical point. Consider the line of curvature $C_1\subset S$ starting from $p$ whose direction coincides with the principal direction $T_1$. Then, the normal curvature of $C_1$ is $k_N=k_1$ (the first principal curvature). My question is the following one:
"Is it true or false that the geodesic curvature $k_G$ of $C_1$ coincides with the second principal curvature $k_2$ ?"
Thanks for any answer!

No. Consider a cylinder and a vertical line on it. Then, $k_g=0$ but the second principal curvature is non-zero (being minus the inverse of the radius of the circle).
